# How do I pass this array to a function which already has other input, without nesting the arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an array called `systemFolders`, which contains folders that I want to ignore. I want to pass that array to the `gulp.src` function, together with another value (`'**/*.{md,markdown}'`).

But since the `gulp.src` function is already receiving the other value, the array `systemFolders` ends up being an array within an array, which causes an error.

How can I pass it the array of folders to ignore, as well as the other value?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var markdown = require('gulp-markdown');

var systemFolders = ['!node_modules/**/*', '!.git/**/*', '!README.md', '!_**/*'];

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.{md,markdown}', systemFolders])
    .pipe(markdown())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_dist'));
});
```

Comment: should I create a new array, and append both the string and the array to that so that it's one value again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
gulp.src(['**/*.{md,markdown}'].concat(systemFolders)])
```

Comment: Cool it works! I would like to omit the `!` from the strings in `systemFolders` and just prefix all values with a `!` on the fly. Would you know how to prefix all values in the array with a `!`?

Comment: @Sam use `Array.prototype.map()`.